# How to combine RNN with CNN?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to combine LSTM with CNN but I got stuck because of an error.
Here is the model I'm trying to implement:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28, 28,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(1,32), activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(37))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

and error happens in the first LSTM layer:

```
ERROR: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_12: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Comment: Check this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/

Comment: In order to give you a really good answer, we need to understand "what do you want to be a sequence" from your data. Are you working with images? Do you want a sequence to be like a movie with many images? Or do you want to have columns as a sequence, or rows.... or maybe it's not images and the data means something else?

Answer (score 6):

The input of LSTM layer should be a 3D array which represents a sequence or a timeseries (this is what the error is trying to say: `expected ndim=3`). However, in your model the input of LSTM layer, which is actually the output of the Dense layer before it, is a 2D array (i.e. `found ndim=2`). To make it into a 3D array of shape `(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)`, one solution is to use a `RepeatVector` layer to repeat it as much as the number of timesteps (which you need to specify in your code):

```
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_timesteps))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_timesteps,32), activation='relu'))
```